# clock phase and clock polarity in SPI

Tags: c, protocols

I having a simple doubts regarding SPI. I have went through the SPI protocol. Every thing i understood. But i didn't know about Clock phase and Clock polarity.

```
    As there are 4 wires(MOSI, MISO, CS and SCK). I came to know from document,
```

there are 4 modes of operation in SPI depends on Clock phase and clock polarity. for example If the phase of the clock is zero (i.e. CPHA = 0) data is latched at the rising edge of the clock with CPOL = 0, and at the falling edge of the clock with CPOL = 1. As per my understand, to latch a data, the clock need to do as below,

```
#define CPOL                     1  // Set CPOL to 1 or 0
#define CPHA                     1  // Set CPHA to 1 or 0

#if CPHA
   #define SCK_POST
   #if CPOL
      #define SCK_INIT 1
      #define SCK_PRE  SCK=0
      #define SCK_MID  SCK=1
   #else
      #define SCK_INIT 0
      #define SCK_PRE  SCK=1
      #define SCK_MID  SCK=0
   #endif
#else
   #define SCK_PRE
   #if CPOL
      #define SCK_INIT 1
      #define SCK_MID  SCK=0
      #define SCK_POST SCK=1
   #else
      #define SCK_INIT 0
      #define SCK_MID  SCK=1
      #define SCK_POST SCK=0
   #endif
#endif


     1. My question is how the clock phase and clock polarity is configured.
```

Since there is no pin for Clock phase and clock polarity.

```
    2. Why 4 modes are there, it seems two mode is enough.
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Clock_polarity_and_phase

Comment: "Since there is no pin for Clock phase and clock polarity." Right. You don't configure us with a pin, but with a bit in a register. Your device manual will tell you which bit it is.

Comment: What happen if i use bit banging

Answer (score 2):

re. why 4 modes, polarity determines the idle state of the clock and phase determines which edge data read/write occurs on, so this results in 2×2 = 4 different possibilities. (See [diagrams](https://www.diolan.com/dln_doc/spi-transfer-modes.html).) Technically one mode would be “enough” for transferring data in this manner, but instead of forcing everyone to implement one specific mode, SPI allows these four possibilities for greater flexibility.

As for how to configure clock phase and polarity, it depends on the device you are working with, and you don't specify any. Typically the device has a register with bits corresponding to clock phase and polarity. Some chips may implement an SPI-like 3-wire protocol that is not configurable, and you need to configure other devices on the bus to match it.